# How can i chose different data templates for different items in listbox?

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I know the question I am asking is normally not encourentered in business applications. However i have encourentered such a need today.

The photos in my listbox are coming from two sources :- One is offcourse from database and other is coming from facebook. I have the user's photo link using facebook C# SDK. Thus i need to have two different data templates as well as binding set up that way. How can i solve this problem? Oh! and yeah i don't want to put up two listboxes on screen and do patch work by putting one listbox exclusively for images coming from my server and other which are coming from facebook.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same thing since i heard that DataTemplateSelector was missing in Silverlight.

Came across this article that might help anyone else that is looking.
[SLTemplateSelector](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLTemplateSelector.aspx)